# Storing data to json in .tsx file but its giving error on using require

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript

I want to save some data to a json file but its showing error

```
ERROR in src/app/layout/stormReactDiagram/canvas/BodyWidget.tsx(59,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
src/app/layout/stormReactDiagram/canvas/BodyWidget.tsx(187,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
```

Using this link as a guide url: https://www.npmjs.com/package/write-json-file

Tried changing types in tsconfig.app.json file doesn't work for me

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: here it is: https://codeshare.io/5vNxl4